# Detect paired bluetooth devices from application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, external-accessory

How to discover non-apple compliant Bluetooth devices with iPhone..???

I have made an app where i need to detect non- apple compliant Bluetooth car kit with my iPhone.i have to detect Bluetooth devices paired with my iPhone  when car kit comes in range i have to call a method. Unable to detect device using external accessory framework. so any help regarding this will be appreciable.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  am not from iPhone but i think Bluetooth communication to external devices for non-jailbroken iOS devices is restricted to MFi-compliant Bluetooth hardware.